# Why do we estimate the Minimum mass when we are dealing with exoplanets?

Tags: star, exoplanet, mass

While solving astronomy problems dealing with exoplanets, I always see that the question asks for minimum mass instead of the mass. Why is that so and why is the calculated mass minimum mass?

example problem:
"A 0.7 solar mass star 35.8 pc away from us is known to have an exo-planet with an orbital
period of 2.82 days around the star. If this produces a radial velocity of 64 m/s about the
center of mass of the star, estimate the minimum mass of the exo-planet (in terms of the
solar mass)."

Comment: It's a projection effect that is fundamental to the radial velocity method - you're measuring $\rm m\, \sin i$, where $\rm i$ is the inclination of the planetary orbital plane w.r.t the observer, and not $\rm m$.

Comment: Correct. Radial velocity is only the velocity in direction to-from (radial) observer so need to take component.